# Redirect domain to IP preserving domain name

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Howdie do,

I need to redirect a domain to an IP address but preserving the domain name

For example, when a user enters jeremysdomain.com/wp-admin, it should redirect them to the IP 123.456.789.123, but the hostname should still be jeremysdomain.com/wp-admin

I currently have my .htaccess with the following:

```
Redirect permanent / 123.456.789.123
```

The issue is the URL in the browser becomes 123.456.789.123 when I actually need it to stay jeremysdomain.com/wp-admin, but still redirect to the IP address

I know you could use mod_rewrite, however, I'm not sure how you would preserve the domain name through the redirect.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"**Redirect**" means to respond to a browser's request by telling the browser that what it's looking for is *over at this other location*. The browser then loads that other location, and that's why the address bar changes. The browser *must* show what URL it's loading.

What you are asking for is a reverse proxy, the browser isn't told where the other location is, and instead the server submits a new request on the browser's behalf to the other location. In order to do this you need to have mod_proxy loaded. Then using mod_rewrite, something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} jeremysdomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://123.456.789.123/$1 [L,P]
```

The `P` flag tells mod_rewrite to reverse proxy the request instead of redirecting it.

What you really need to do is go to your domain's DNS server and simply make it to "jeremysdomain.com" resolves to 123.456.789.123.

Comment: Jon, thank you for your reply. I would do the DNS to make sure jeremysdomaind.com resolves to 123.4456.789.123, but it wouldn't work for every case. I believe based off what you're mentioning about reverse proxying is what I need. I'm going to do some research and investigate further. Thanks again